# I am getting an error message: Exception: You do not have permission to call DriveApp.getFileById. Required permissions:

Tags: permissions, required, scopes

Exception: You do not have permission to call getFileById Required permissions: (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly || https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive)

My approved scopes include, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive

Answer (score 0):

If you are using triggers, deleting and recreating existing triggers will launch an Oauth page. This will give your script the required permissions